# HTTP POST with request body

Tags: java, http, azure-active-directory, http-post

For this request, I am trying to set the entity, however when I do `request.setEntity`, it says required type **`HttpEntity`**, on upcasting it to `HttpEntity` as `request.setEntity((HttpEntity) entity)` it still gives me exception.

```java
final HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
    String json = "{\n"
        + "      \"id\": \"1\",\n"
        + "      \"method\": \"GET\",\n"
        + "      \"url\": \"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/xyz/members\"\n"
        + "    }";
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json);
    request.setEntity(entity);
```

Comment: It would be great if you attach an exception log.

Comment: The code runs without any exception with httpclient:4.3.6 Could you please indicate your httpclient version?

Comment: httpclient:4.5.10

Comment: Still no error. Maybe checking imports helps...

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;

Comment: correct, i was using "com.signalfx.shaded.apache.http.entity.StringEntity" which was causing the issue

Comment: Hello @ShambhaviRai, could you please post your solution as an answer for reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using "com.signalfx.shaded.apache.http.entity.StringEntity" instead of "import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity" which was causing the issue.